# Rails 3 default_scope sort by foreign key object name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, activerecord, scope

I'm having a little trouble figuring this out: I have a model `Machine` that has a foreign key on a `locations` table, and I want the default scope of `Machine` to sort by `location.name`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a join to your other table.

```
class Machine < ActiveRecord::Base

  default_scope joins(:location).order('locations.name')

end
```

Make sure the relation you call in `joins` matches the one defined in your `Machine` model.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in your Machine model:

```
has_many :locations, :order => "name ASC"
```

Comment: This defines the relationship between the two tables, it will not order Machine records by their associated Location names.

Comment: Seems I didn't understand the question. I let the answer there cause it could still be useful to order children objects.

Comment: @Douglas, you're defimitely right. In my opinion, a mere comment would have been enough to make me reread the question :)